predict() function fails for lmer in R when NAs present in dataset
The issue is not how to format/obtain data but how to run predictions for linear mixed effect model for given set os estimated fixed effects in case of NAs present in the data.
The predict() function fails for lmer when NAs present in the data set, e.g.

see attached, LMEM_TEST_withNA.csv.
The R code reads (data rescaling etc. left out for simplicity)
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)

#### Read in data 
fileName = paste0('LMEM_TEST')
DF <- read.csv(paste0(fileName,'.csv'), check.names=FALSE, header = T) #
DF$SEX <- as.factor(DF$SEX)
DF$TRT <- as.factor(DF$TRT)

# Fit the linear mixed-effects model
model_lmer <- lmer(ENDPOINT ~ TIME + TRT + SEX + AGE + WT + BIOMARKER1 + BIOMARKER2 + TRT*TIME + (1 | ID), 
                   data = DF)

# Check the summary of the model_lmer
print(summary(model_lmer))

# plot data and predictions
p = ggplot(data = DF, aes(x=TIME, y=ENDPOINT, colour=factor(ID))) +
  facet_wrap(~ ID) +
  geom_point(size=2) +
  geom_line(aes(y=predict(model_lmer)),linewidth=1)
print(p)

The error message I get is
Error in `geom_line()` at Stack/LMEM_withNA.R:28:1:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (96).
✖ Fix the following mappings: `y`.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Any ideas how to fix it?
UPDATE:
With the ideas from Ben I updated the code which now reads
model_lmer <- lmer(ENDPOINT ~ TIME + TRT + SEX + AGE + WT + BIOMARKER1 + BIOMARKER2 + TRT*TIME + (1 | ID), 
                   data = DF)

model_lmer2 <- update(model_lmer, na.action = na.exclude)
p2 <- predict(model_lmer2)
nrow(DF) == length(p2)  ## TRUE
any(is.na(p2))  ## TRUE

p = ggplot(data = DF, aes(x=TIME, y=ENDPOINT, colour=factor(ID))) +
  facet_wrap(~ ID) +
  geom_point(size=2) +
  geom_line(aes(y=p2),linewidth=1, color="black")
print(p)

but the predicted ENDPOINT time series is now patchy, see below plots for ID=1,...,3. ENDPOINT has no NAs however. Any comments would be very appreciated.

UPDATE2: following Ben suggestions, when running default lmer (i.e. with na.action = na.omit)
p1 <- predict(model_lmer)
nrow(DF) == length(p1)  ## FALSE 
any(is.na(p1))  ## FALSE
print(p1)

results es expected in
> print(p1)
       1        2        4        6        7        8        9       10       12       13       15 
65.94565 69.85143 66.12818 65.41932 67.40121 67.16445 65.44844 66.37758 65.22547 66.32646 65.43112 
      16       17       18       20       22       23       24       25       26       28       29 
67.28522 67.52091 69.09569 66.61406 64.93061 65.02846 66.41027 77.08061 78.95098 74.98504 74.40791 
      31       32       33       34       36       38       39       40       41       42       44 
74.32924 74.46698 70.21084 70.32008 66.96311 65.83663 66.74459 68.64914 62.45423 61.71591 61.90722 
      45       47       48       49       50       52       54       55       56       57       58 
62.72561 63.47417 65.47317 69.19177 69.18447 68.40221 69.73793 69.95962 71.33414 80.11021 83.02098 
      60       62       63       64       65       66       68       69       71       72       73 
82.03436 83.40753 83.21883 83.67255 70.86396 72.12438 67.83296 70.62668 72.19932 71.93983 77.07972 
      74       76       78       79       80       81       82       84       85       87       88 
79.83580 74.90118 77.89458 78.27096 79.17085 80.35120 81.19802 78.98112 78.86165 80.30483 82.07673 
      89       90       92       94       95       96 
63.62631 66.71788 62.41824 64.86857 65.00069 66.77993

and p2 part:
model_lmer2 <- update(model_lmer, na.action = na.exclude)
p2 <- predict(model_lmer2)
nrow(DF) == length(p2)  ## TRUE
any(is.na(p2))  ## TRUE
print(p2)

only adds the NAs:
> print(p2)
       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10       11 
65.94565 69.85143       NA 66.12818       NA 65.41932 67.40121 67.16445 65.44844 66.37758       NA 
      12       13       14       15       16       17       18       19       20       21       22 
65.22547 66.32646       NA 65.43112 67.28522 67.52091 69.09569       NA 66.61406       NA 64.93061 
      23       24       25       26       27       28       29       30       31       32       33 
65.02846 66.41027 77.08061 78.95098       NA 74.98504 74.40791       NA 74.32924 74.46698 70.21084 
      34       35       36       37       38       39       40       41       42       43       44 
70.32008       NA 66.96311       NA 65.83663 66.74459 68.64914 62.45423 61.71591       NA 61.90722 
      45       46       47       48       49       50       51       52       53       54       55 
62.72561       NA 63.47417 65.47317 69.19177 69.18447       NA 68.40221       NA 69.73793 69.95962 
      56       57       58       59       60       61       62       63       64       65       66 
71.33414 80.11021 83.02098       NA 82.03436       NA 83.40753 83.21883 83.67255 70.86396 72.12438 
      67       68       69       70       71       72       73       74       75       76       77 
      NA 67.83296 70.62668       NA 72.19932 71.93983 77.07972 79.83580       NA 74.90118       NA 
      78       79       80       81       82       83       84       85       86       87       88 
77.89458 78.27096 79.17085 80.35120 81.19802       NA 78.98112 78.86165       NA 80.30483 82.07673 
      89       90       91       92       93       94       95       96 
63.62631 66.71788       NA 62.41824       NA 64.86857 65.00069 66.77993 

which means I still heve no predictions for ENDPOINT at the time points where BIOMARKERs are NA. I was under the impression that there is a way to calculate ENDPOINT at exact these time points. Where do I go wrong???
IDEA: I guess I perform lmer on dataset after excluding all records with NA and updatedd model without the BIOMERKERs and subsequently merge these predictions?
UPDATE3:
I did run lmer on the two disjunct data subsets as described above (IDEA) and got what I wanted but there must be a smarter way to achieve that.


What do you expect the multiplication between a number and "not a number" to be?

Not sure what you mean. If say BIOMARKER1 is NA for a time point than its contribution to ENDPOINT is NA and should be omitted. Instead, as the figure shows, it impacts the prediction which incorrect. Please, elaborate if I am mistaken.

Re: your latest edit: but you have gotten the model predictions (they are stored in the p2 object), so the issues does seem to be the plotting code.

You are re-including the NA observations in your predictions now, so you fixed the inputs being of different length but for obvious reasons NA can neither be calculated with nor plotted. Remove these records from your input dataset and only then run the model & plot.

The way that you are calling predict(), with the default newdata=NULL argument, will only give predictions for the rows of data in the data frame you used to fit the model. That's generally true for all R predict() functions for different types of models. You can generate predictions for any set of values that you want by including a data frame with those values as the newdata argument. See the manual page for predict.merMod if you want to include random effects in your predictions.

This is not the predict() method failing, but your plotting machinery.
The default method for handling NA values is na.omit(): from ?lme4::lmer,

na.action: a function that indicates what should happen when the data
contain ‘NA’s.  The default action (‘na.omit’, inherited from
the 'factory fresh' value of ‘getOption("na.action")’) strips
any observations with any missing values in any variables.

If you use na.action = na.exclude instead, that will fill in predicted values of NA for the observations with missing information. (This should possibly be documented somewhere in lme4, but it's not specific to lme4 — it's part of the basic NA-handling paradigm in R ...)
Here's a little illustration with lm (for simplicity):
mm <- mtcars
mm$hp[1] <- NA
model <- lm(mpg ~ hp, data = mm)
p1 <- predict(model)
nrow(mm) == length(p1)  ## FALSE
any(is.na(p1))  ## FALSE

Now add na.exclude:
model2 <- update(model, na.action = na.exclude)
p2 <- predict(model2)
nrow(mm) == length(p2)  ## TRUE
any(is.na(p2))  ## TRUE


Ben, I followed your advise, see UPDATE, but the plot is now very patchy.
